# Encoding a String in NetSuite SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: encoding, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have to perform the following encoding on a string:

1. Calculate SHA1 hash value, with output in hexadecimal format
2. Apply a BASE64 encoding to the resulted hash

I'm trying to do this in the code below, 'str' being the input and 'digest' the final encoded string.

I've tried different ways without much success. The current code (below) throws an error:

*WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contains illegal character for hexBinary: crypto.SecretKey*

```
var str = nonce + timestamp + secret;

var secureString = HTTPS.createSecureString({
        input: str
    });

secureString = secureString.hash({
        algorithm: CRYPTO.HashAlg.SHA1
    });

var hexString = HTTPS.createSecretKey({
        encoding: HTTPS.Encoding.HEX,
        guid: secureString
    });

var digest = ENCODE.convert({
        string: hexString,
        inputEncoding: ENCODE.Encoding.HEX,
        outputEncoding: ENCODE.Encoding.BASE_64
    });
```